# How to Parse the ajax script in DOM Parser?

Tags: php

I parsing scores from http://sports.in.msn.com/football-world-cup-2014/south-africa-v-brazil/1597383

I able to parse all the attributes. But I can't able to parse the time.

I Used

```
$homepages = file_get_html("http://sports.in.msn.com/football-world-cup-2014/south-africa-v-brazil/1597383");

$teama = $homepages->find('span[id="clock"]');
```

Kindly help me

Comment: i dont think, this is the way to scrape the time, as it is dynamically loaded. upon scraping the site, the initial node value of `<span id="clock"></span>`. then the value if loaded after the page load thru ajax. maybe if you can access an api that they are using maybe this could be your solution on getting the time.

Comment: maybe instead of scraping the site, maybe you can process JSON values. sample http://sports.in.msn.com/liveplayajax/SOCCERMATCH/match/gsm/en-in/1597383

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the that particular site is loading the values dynamically (thru AJAX request), you cant really parse the value upon initial load.

```
<span id="clock"></span> // this tends to be empty initial load
```

Normal scrapping:

```
 $homepages = file_get_contents("http://sports.in.msn.com/football-world-cup-2014/south-africa-v-brazil/1597383");
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 @$doc->loadHTML($homepages);
 $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
 $query = $xpath->query("//span[@id='clock']");
 foreach($query as $value) {
     echo $value->nodeValue; // the traversal is correct, but this will be empty
 }
```

My suggestion is instead of scraping it, you will need to have to access it thru a request also, since it is a time (of course, as the match goes on this will change and change until the game has ended). Or you can also use their request.

```
$url = 'http://sports.in.msn.com/liveplayajax/SOCCERMATCH/match/gsm/en-in/1597383';
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($contents, true);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

Should yield something like (a part of it actually):

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [Code] => 
        [CommentId] => -1119368663
        [CommentType] => manual
        [Description] => FULL-TIME: South Africa 0-5 Brazil.
        [Min] => 90'
        [MinExtra] => (+3)
        [View] => 
        [ViewHint] => 
        [ViewIndex] => 0
        [EditKey] => 
        [TrackingValues] => 
        [AopValue] => 
    )
```

You should get the `90'` by using foreach. Consider this example:

```
foreach($data['Commentary']['CommentaryItems'] as $key => $value) {
    if(stripos($value['Description'], 'FULL-TIME') !== false) {
        echo $value['Min'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Should print: `90'`

Comment: Thanks a lot! and how to print [Min] => 90' alone

Comment: If I use another another match link I'm not able to get time. I used mozilla firebug and able to see like this in DOM `<TextNode textContent="90:00">` Its better if I able to get ongoing match time rather than commentary time. Kindly help me in this.

Comment: @user3354786 yes i maybe able to help you at that, but maybe you could share it with a link, is it on that same page too?

Comment: for this match`http://sports.in.msn.com/football-world-cup-2014/argentina-v-slovenia/1630386`

Comment: @user3354786 are you sure its `<TextNode textContent="90:00">`? inside that page? im searching in browsers console but cant find one

Comment: Yeah Sure, I found that using mozilla firefox firebug in DOM